# how do i run BeautifulSoup in my python 3 version?

Tags: python

i am using this statement in my python 36 version:
       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, then i get a syntax error like this:
You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work. You need to convert the code, either by installing it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'

how do i fix this?
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: `pip install -u beautifulsoup4` ?

Comment: [Their doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation) mentions such problem and advise to reinstall.

Comment: What OS are you using?